# Leaked AWS credentials, Amazon Web Services credentials may be exposed - Google play console

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

Recently, i submitted android application to google play store is being rejected.

As my app upload to / download from AWS S3, so i put S3_ACCESS_KEY and S3_SECRET_KEY in my build config file, with an old version AWS SDK, i can upload /download successfully.

I search some solutions of replacement like amplify, or set up a server to handle it.

Is there any very simple, quick solution that i can solve the problem??

## Leaked AWS credentials

Your app contains Exposed Amazon Web Services Credentials.

Vulnerable classes:

sv:deadline:04/16/2022

## Amazon Web Services credentials may be exposed

Your Amazon Web Services credentials may be exposed.

This exposure of your credentials could lead to unauthorized access to your AWS account, which may include associated excessive charges, and potentially unauthorized access to your data and your users' data.

[Reference image for the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROPEK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Embedding AWS credentials on any client-side apps is a scary idea. In order to solve this challenge, you would have to use either CloudFront or S3 Signed URLs.

This approach requires the generation of short-lived upload/download URLs in one of your APIs so that it could send back to the client-application a URL where we can directly upload/download assets to/from an S3 bucket.

It allows us to avoid the hardcoding of AWS credentials on client-applications and have dynamic short-lived URLs dedicated for one-time upload/download operations on-demand.

It shouldn't be that hard and you could follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@lakshmanLD/upload-file-to-s3-using-lambda-the-pre-signed-url-way-158f074cda6c) to learn more about S3 signed urls.